# How to get attachment caption (get_the_excerpt gives parent post excerpt) ?

Tags: attachments, excerpt

I am displaying the attachments on the parent post page with this code :

```
        $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order'=> 'ASC', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $attachments_url[] = $my_image;
            $attachments_caption[] = get_the_excerpt();
            }
        }
```

problem is that the excerpt doesn't get the attachment's caption but the post excerpt.

do you know how to display the attachment's captions ?
thank you

Comment: auto answer. $attachments_caption[] = $attachment->post_excerpt; is working

Comment: Post that as an **answer**, rather than as a **comment** to your question - and then be sure to come back later and **accept** the answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

[`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) should work for getting caption just fine.

Your issue is that it looks for post to process in global variables and in your code there you are not setting it up with attachments you are iterating through.

You need to use [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) for it to work.

Other way would be something like:

```
get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment->ID);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $id )` and return everything you need for the attachment.

You'll receive an array with this:

- id
- title
- filename
- url
- link
- alt
- author
- description
- caption
- name
- status
- uploadedTo
- date
- modified
- menuOrder
- mime
- type
- subtype
- icon
- dateFormatted
- nonces
- editLink
- sizes
- width
- height
- fileLength
- compat

Check the Codex: [wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Link only answers aren't well recieved answers. Please post some relevant code/examples/description from the link, and keep the link for additional info and author credit

Answer (score -1):

This will fix your issue

```
$attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
$total_attachments = count( $attachments );
if( $total_attachments ){
 for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ){
     echo $attachments[$i]['title']; 
     echo $attachments[$i]['caption'];
     echo $attachments[$i]['id'];
     echo $attachments[$i]['location'];
     echo $attachments[$i]['mime'];
     echo $attachments[$i]['filesize']; 
 }
}
```